# __declspec(dllimport) and extern (OBS)

Tags: c, plugins, dllimport, extern, dllexport

i was going through the OBS source to understand how they did the plugin system. I'm stuck on one part that i cannot reproduce and that i didn't find the answer anywhere.

To share the function with the plugin (dll) that OBS load, there is a pointer to an `APIInterface`. This pointer is named `API` so i'll call it like that from now. This variable is declare in `OBSApi\APIInterface.h` and the declaration is: `BASE_EXPORT extern APIInterface *API;` where `BASE_EXPORT` is defined in `OBSApi\Utility\XT_Windows.h` with

```
#if defined(NO_IMPORT)
    #define BASE_EXPORT
#elif !defined(BASE_EXPORTING)
    #define BASE_EXPORT     __declspec(dllimport)
#else
    #define BASE_EXPORT     __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
```

Finally, in the the constructor of a `OBS` object (in the main program) it initialize `API` with `API = CreateOBSApiInterface();`.

But, i cannot compile if there is a variable that i only declare & not initialize. So, i was wondering what i'm missing, how can this `API` variable be shared among the plugin ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the plugin is doing in this case is using a global variable that is exported   using `__declspec(dllexport)` from the plugin into your program.
In your program it is imported using `__declspec(dllimport)`.

The variable itself is defined within the plugin and the `extern` tells your program that the declaration is not found in the current compilation unit, so it will be found when the linker goes off to look for it.

A small example of how this would look is as follows:

### plugin.h

```
/* define the int* as an exported external. */
BASE_EXPORT extern int* exportedInt;
```

### plugin.c

```
#define BASE_EXPORTING /* so the macro shown will export. */
#include "plugin.h"

/* actually define the int* so it exists for the linker to find. */
int* exportedInt = NULL;
```

### your_program.c

```
#include "plugin.h"

/* use the int* in your program, the linker will find it in plugin.cpp. */
exportedInt = CreateIntPointerFunction();
```

The plugin could then be compiled as a static (`.lib`) or dynamic (`.lib` and `.dll`) library which you can then link in with your code.

With a dynamic library you can choose to:

- Dynamically load it at runtime, no need for the `.lib` but you will need to manually find the values and entry points.
- Link it at compilation using the `.lib`, `.dll` combo which will automatically tell the program where to find all the entry points and values.

As long as you include the header file in the compilation unit and tell the linker where to find the `.lib` when not doing runtime loading, you'll be able to use the exported functions and variables in your own program.

Comment: Ok, so if i understand well it follow the following steps. 1. Compile a dll, `plugin.dll` that initialize & export the `API`. 2. Compile the main program that link `plugin.lib`. 3. I can know create a dll that link `plugin.lib` & import `API` and i share this variable with the main program. Moreover, i can know load & unload my module in runtime.

Comment: You have almost all of that correct, i'll add in more information in the answer to help.